# Calculating standard error for amplitude and phase of estimates for amplitudes of fourier elements (time series context)

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, standard-error, seasonality, fourier-transform

I have a time series consisting of a mean, a cosine harmonic wave, and seasonal ARIMA errors, and the seasonality period of both is 7 days:

$$
\begin{align}
x_t &= \mu + h_t + u_t \\
h_t &= Amp\cdot \cos(\omega_s t - \varphi) \; \;\;\text{with}\;\; \omega_s = \frac{2\pi}{7}\\
u_t &= SARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,0)[7]
\end{align}
$$

I nead to estimate SARIMA parameters ($\phi$, $\theta$, $\Phi$) as well as the amplitude ($Amp$) and phase shift ($\varphi$, which indicates where the harmonic element peaks) of $h_t$.
Theoretically, one can model $h_t$ with a Fourier transform of order 1:

$$
f_t = a \cdot \cos(\omega_s) + b \cdot \sin(\omega_s)
$$

By including $\cos(\omega_s)$ and $\sin(\omega_s)$ as an exogeneous regressor in a SARIMA model, and estimate $a$ and $b$ as regression coefficients with their standard errors. However, I need point estimates (and their respective standard errors) of $Amp$ and $\varphi$ instead of $a$ and $b$.

What I had in mind was to write down $h_t$ with the parameters of $f_t$ (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365486/), but with a sine) via

$$
h_t = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \cdot \cos(\omega_s t - \arctan\frac{a}{b}) & b > 0 \\
a \cdot \cos(\omega_s t - \frac{\pi}{2}) & b = 0 \\
-\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \cdot \cos(\omega_s t - \arctan\frac{a}{b}) & b < 0 
\end{cases}
$$

Thus

$$
\begin{align}
Amp = &\begin{cases}
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} & b > 0 \\
a, \; \; & b = 0 \\
-\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} & b < 0
\end{cases}
\\
\\
\varphi = &\begin{cases} 
\arctan\frac{a}{b} & b \neq 0 \\
\frac{\pi}{2} & b = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

And approximately calculate the standard errors of $Amp$ and $\varphi$ (as nonlinear combinations of $a$ and $b$) using, e.g., the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) as explained in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152049/) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446699/) answers.

**However**, since $Amp$ is piecewise—and hence non-differentiable—the differentiability assumption of the delta method is violated. Apart from the standard errors, intuitively, I cannot imagine what would happen to $Amp$ and $\varphi$ if the confidence intervals of $a$ and/or $b$ covers (or gets close) to zero.

Is there a way around it? Thanks in advance!

---

### MWE and reproducible code:

```r
library(forecast)
library(sarima)

set.seed(1)
N <- 1000 # time series length

# Mean 
mu <- 1

# Harmonic component of the mean structure
amp <- 3
omega_s <- 2 * pi/7 # angular frequency for f = 1/7
phase_peak <- 3.5 * omega_s

h_t <- amp * cos(c(1:N) - phase_peak)

# Seasonal arima noise
u_t <- sarima::sim_sarima(n = N,
               model = list(ar = 0.5,
                            ma = 0.2,
                            sar = 0.3,
                            nseasons = 7,
                            sigma2 = 16),
               n.start = 100
               )


x_t <- mu + h_t + u_t
x_t <- ts(x_t, frequency = 7)

# Making sine-cosine pairs for external regressors
rh <- forecast::fourier(x_t, K = 1)

# Estimating the model
arima(x_t,
      order = c(1,0,1),
      seasonal = c(1,0,0),
      xreg = rh)
#> 
#> Call:
#> arima(x = x_t, order = c(1, 0, 1), seasonal = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = rh)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1     ma1    sar1  intercept    S1-7     C1-7
#>       0.4134  0.2434  0.3147     0.6642  0.4324  -3.1029
#> s.e.  0.0484  0.0518  0.0301     0.4062  0.3910   0.3909
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 17.38:  log likelihood = -2847.3,  aic = 5708.6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Which shows good estimates of all parameters, and the manual calculation of the amplitude ($Amp = \sqrt{0.432^2  + (-3.102)^2} = 3.133$) and phase shift ($\varphi = \arctan \frac{-3.103}{0.432} = -1.286$) seem "reasonable".